# Counting how many numbers in an array are between 1.5 - 35 C#

Tags: c#, inner-classes

I am trying to work out how to count how many numbers in an array fall between the values of, 1.5 - 35. I am struggling to work out which method I should use to achieve this. I was thinking maybe a for-each embedded loop but then the more I think about it the more I question that method. Any help would be appreciated on how I may achieve this, I will post my current code below as I have already worked out how to calculate the average and minimum price for the equation.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        read_stock_price();
    }
    static void read_stock_price()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter how many stocks to enter price for: ");
        int numStocks = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        double[] arrayinput = new double[numStocks];

        for (int i = 0; i < numStocks; ++i)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter price for stock number: ");
            arrayinput[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        double sum = arrayinput.Sum();
        double average = sum / numStocks;

        Console.WriteLine("Average price: {0} out of {1} stocks", average, numStocks);
        Console.WriteLine("Minimum price: {0}", arrayinput.Min());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortest way is [Enumerable.Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var count = arrayinput.Count(x => 1.5 < x && x < 35.0);
```

Comment: Great, this does indeed look like the shortest way!
This will work great, would you be able to explain to me what this part of the code means in my situation, I am just wanting to further understand the what it means? Thanks!

x => 1.5 < x

Comment: It's a lambda expression: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx . It's a basically a function that receives a double `x` and returns the boolean `(1.5 < x) && (x < 35.0)`. And you're passing that function to the `Count()` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ instead of a `for-each`.  First filter the array then count the elements.

```
var count = arrayinput
   .Where(x => 1.5 <= x && x <= 35.0)
   .Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

if we assumed **arrayinput** is your filled array you can use this:

```
     double[] arrayinput = new double[numStocks];

     double[] filteredArray = arrayinput.Where(p => p > 1.5 && p < 3.5).ToArray();

     int count = filteredArray.Count();
```

this code filter your array with value between 1.5 & 3.5.

Comment: Maybe you meant `filteredArray.Count()` instead of `arrayinput.Count()`? And also, since it's an array, it's better to use length: `filteredArray.Length`.